# What are some Django best practice for creating objects to test on

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, testcase

The way I've been testing on code that requires a temporary Object to be created seems messy. I am hoping there is a cleaner and more intuitive way of doing it.

On setup, I run a function setUpTestData that is in charge of creating temporary Objects that my tests may use later on. This has become a bit cluttered with the nested Objects I am having to create within it due to ForeignKey relationships.

Here's an example of what I am working with:

```
class Test_query_alarm(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Device.objects.create(
            site=Site.objects.create(
                group=Group.objects.create(
                    name='TestGroup'
                ),
                name='TestSiteName',
                address='TestAddress',
                gps_coordinates='TestGpsCoordinates',
                contact=Contact.objects.create(
                    first_name='TestFirstName',
                    last_name='TestLastName',
                    phone='TestPhoneNumber',
                    email='test@gmail.com'
                )
            ),
            ip_address='ip-here',
            snmp_port_number='port-here',
            http_port_number='port-here',
            location='Houston',
            snmp_version='SNMPV2',
            type='Modem',
            manufacturer='Commscope'
        )
```

As you can see, I am generating the Device object. But it's also requiring three other objects to be created alongside it. Is there any advice someone can give me here, whether it be database design, test design, or something else.

Comment: You can Django shell (python manage.py shell)

Comment: I play with the Django shell for quick coding output but I'm not sure how I would use it for creating automated unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [django-autofixture](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-autofixture), you can use it for quickly creating objects, it will fill your fields with random data according to the field type, or could specify the data you want the created object has in some field.

It also will follow relations if you told to do so. It has a lot of features.

Thanks to @HåkenLid for this useful link: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/fixtures/

Happy testing.

Comment: Here's some other packages as well:
https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/fixtures/

Comment: Ah, so that's what a fixture is. Good to know, thank you.